# Can we ask the user to select app to lunch on button clicked in Objective-C

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Good day,

Is there any possible way to ask the user to choose which app to lunch when he clicked on a button.

for example in Android when the user clicks on a link, the android system asks the user to select between "Internet app" and other installed browsers "Chrome" for example, and this is done by setting the action for the Intent object.

how can we do such thing in Objective-C !!

Thank You All :)

Comment: You need to create a hack like this:- If your app able to open url from both ways(canOpenUrl and using uiactivitycontroller), then pop up a view to user asking for which way. Click on particular selected button, do the selective task. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is not possible is iOS. you can implement in two ways this concept . safari is the default one in iOS

1. CanOpenURL concept- [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/), [Tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html)
2. share using UIActivityController - [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/), [tutorial](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/)